# PROLOG defining 'delete' predicate

Tags: prolog

```
delete(X,[X|R],[_|R]).
delete(X,[F|R],[F|S]) :-
    delete(X,R,S).
```

Above is my definition of delete predicate, for delete(X,L,R), intended to delete every occurrence of X in L with result R.

I had queried below, and get "`G2397797`". What does this string stand for?

```
?- delete(1,[1,2,3,4,5],X).
X = [_G2397797, 2, 3, 4, 5] .
```

Comment: `delete(X, [X|R], [_|R]).` doesn't just delete `X`, but replaces it with an anonymous variable (`_`). Is that what you really want?

Answer (score 1):

If you simply correct your first clause and remove the unnecessary anonymous variable, you would get:

```
delete_each(X, [X|L], L).
delete_each(X, [Y|Ys], [Y|Zs]) :-
        delete_each(X, Ys, Zs).
```

This will use unification, and delete each occurrence of X in the list upon backtracking:

```
?- delete_each(a, [a,b,a,c], R).
R = [b, a, c] ;
R = [a, b, c] ;
false.
```

Do you see how this is identical to `select/3`?

If you want to delete all occurrences of X in the list, you can see the [answer by @coder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40572093/1812457).

Answer (score 0):

In the answer you get `X = [_G2397797, 2, 3, 4, 5] .`  , _G2397797 is not a string it is a variable that is not instantiated. This is due to the clause:

```
delete(X,[X|R],[_|R]).
```

which places in the output list  an anonymous variable "_". You could write `delete(X,[X|R],R).`

But this has multiple problems. Firstly it only deletes the **first** occurrence of X not all because in the above clause when you find one you succeed. Also you haven't thought the case of empty list which is also the base case of the recursion. Finally in your second clause you haven't applied any rule that says F and X differ and this clause give wrong results when F equals to X.

So you could write:

```
delete(_,[],[]).
delete(X,[X|R],S):-delete(X,R,S).
delete(X,[F|R],[F|S]):-dif(X,F),delete(R,S).
```

Comment: There is a very telling comment in the documentation of the [library `delete/3` in SWI-Prolog](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=delete/3), at least: "deprecated: There are too many ways in which one might want to delete elements from a list to justify the name. Think of matching (`=` vs. `==`), delete first/all, be deterministic or not." Either way, I think the delete by OP was meant to be matching with `=`, first only, delete next on backtracking.

Comment: I'm not very sure I understand exactly. You mean something like:                       delete(_,[],[]).
delete(X,[Y|R],S):-(X=Y ->S=[X|T], delete(X,R,T);  delete(X,R,S) ).

Comment: Code in comments is a bit difficult; see my answer

Comment: Thanks Boris !, I understand.